# "nie mo" after python3 manage.py startserver

Tags: python, django, terminal

I'm trying to start local server by using python django, and pycharm returns "nie mo" after python3 manage.py runserver command. Any idea what's the problem?

Comment: you may not be in the correct directory. You can go to the desired one using the **cd** command. That is: cd the path to the project folder. If you have an application, then it must be registered in the INSTALLED_APPS list (settings.py file)